# Assembly .byte array

Tags: assembly, mips, gnu-assembler

I've defined a byte array using

```
.data
letters  : .byte 0:26
```

And i've got some questions : 
1 )  Is the first cell in the array available for use, or its employed for other purpose?
2 ) How can I load the 6 ( for example ) cell of the array ?

I've thought about using :

```
la $t0, letters  # load the array address to $t0
addi $t0, $t0 , 6  # update $t0 in order to get the 6th cell
lb $t1, $t0        # load byte to $t1
```

Is this method valid or should I do it in other way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the processor architecture you are targeting? Please add the appropriate tag next to 'assembly' tag.

Comment: Just FYI, `.byte 0:26` is *not* valid GAS syntax in general for GNU Binutils `as`.  It's specific to the assembler in MARS or SPIM, I assume.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, it is available
2) Like in C the first cell has zero offset.
   So this way you will actually point to the seventh cell.

Comment: Thanks . I'd like to know , the syntex itself is ok  ?
@Vlad Krasnov

Comment: I don't know this specific assembler language. But on x86 it would look similar.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost valid, you are just missing a pair of parentheses for indirect addressing, like so:

```
lb $t1, ($t0) # load byte to $t1
```

Also, the address can include a constant offset, so in your case you don't have to add that separately:

```
lb $t1, 6($t0) # load byte to $t1
```

Note this only works for constants. If you want to index by another register you must do the addition like you did.

Vlad has already answered the other part.